# Why can I not rename a file in Powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to rename an xml file. This is the way I am trying to go about it. But it keeps giving me this error back.

Code:

```
$File = "C:\temp\snapshot.xml"
$HName = hostname
$CurrentTime = Get-Date -Format "MM_dd_yyyy_HH:mm:ss"
$NewFileName = "$HName" + "_" + "$CurrentTime" + "_" + "snapshot.xml"
Rename-Item -Path $File -NewName $NewFileName
```

Error:

```
Rename-Item : Cannot rename the specified target, because it represents a path or device name.
At line:1 char:1
+ Rename-Item -Path $File -NewName $NewFileName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-Item], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

According to this documentation on it from Microsoft it seems like I am doing it right, but I must be missing something.

```
Rename-Item -Path "c:\logfiles\daily_file.txt" -NewName "monday_file.txt"
```

Comment: A filename cannot contain colons. Use a different format for the time component.

Comment: Yes thank you that works.